# Canadian Postal Codes via Bing Maps API

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

A bit of a newb here, although I have some experience with Bing Maps.

Im trying to use the Locations API to search for locations (primarily) in Canada.  My data request is successful and I get back expected data...except for one thing.  Canadian Postal codes are traditionally six characters long.  However, the API only responds with the first three characters.  I realize that only the first 3 characters are needed for geolocation but was wondering if it is possible for Bing to return the whole 6 character value.

My data request looks like this:
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=[MYKEY]&q=1440+Law&ul=43.45297157764435%2C-79.70163702964783

I've trimmed some fields for relevancy.

Can Bing's Locations API return a full Canadian Postal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps Locations API is designed for geocoding and reverse-geocoding, not for address validation.

As you point out, it's generally unnecessary to consider the full postcode for geocoding - the results can be unambiguously identified using a street address and only the first 3 characters of the postcode. So, although I can't say for certain, I'd say the answer is "no".